# Why is this rendering slow? React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, infinite-scroll

I have an api that fetches names(usernames) based on country somewhere along the lines of.

`/names/{countryName}`

and the UI has two tabs - being `Australia` and `India`. For this I'm using material ui tabs in react.

Once the user clicks India it calls `/names/India` and fetches a list of names (close to 200). Similarly it goes for Australia.

When the call is made to the backend I'm showing a loader in the frontend. Then I'm storing the result in an object called `names` in state. `names['India']` and `names['Australia']` is an array of 200 values each. These names are shown in a table with the names and a random image generated from the names. And this is all working fine.

Problem starts when a user switches back and forth the tabs. Since the data is already there in the state, so no new call is made. But even then the rendering is slow. It remains on the old tab until data in new tab is rendered and only then it switches to the new tab and this is misleading to the end user.

I was thinking of using `react-window-infinite-loader` but that is more useful when you are fetching data page by page and the api returns you data that way. But right now, the data is anyway there on state. Why is it taking so much time to render it, how can I avoid this?

Comment: Are the UI components for India and Australia the same?

Comment: @IshanJoshi yes, the UI components are same. all of them have access to the name of the tab chosen and names array (through the state) so they just do `names['tabChosen']` to pass data as props to the component.

Comment: Maybe having 400 elements in the state is hampering your performance

Comment: Have you tried paginating the elements

Comment: @IshanJoshi that's why I'm planning to try out infinite scrolling now. But is that (or pagination) the only option?

Comment: Yes. Along with pagination, you should also check out lazy loading

Comment: You can also try using React.memo or React.useMemo, but it's hard to give any suggestions without seeing some code. These will ensure that react won't have to do expensive rendering calculations if dependencies don't change. My personal preference would be infinite scrolling though. It's always better to initially render 10 items insead of 200.

Comment: You haven't provided any code so who knows

Comment: I thought the situation provided explains the code itself. I will try using the infinite scroll. Thanks all.

Comment: @IshanJoshi  An infinite scroll solved my problem. Thanks.